# How to show a modal after x number of visitors

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-modal, html

I'm trying to have a modal pop up every 50 users for a site survey. I can easily create a modal on the pages I need, but can't figure out a way to have it only show up after x number of visits. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use PHP and MySQL and count the visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write The following code in your theme's functions.php file:

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0";
    }
    return $count;
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}

// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

This part of the code will set the post views. Just place this snippet below within your file.

```
<?php
    setPostViews(get_the_ID());
?>
```

The below code is display the number of views within your posts. So, Write code like this:

```
<?php
    if(getPostViews(get_the_ID()) >= 'x') {
        // Write your popup code here
    }
?>
```